# How to bitshift an array of ints?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an int array of size 50 and the first 49 'slots' are filled and I want to move each of the 49 elements of the array one position along so that the first element in the array is now free.

Is there a way to bit shift the entire array 32 bits? like:

> array[0] >(49)> 32;

some random made up notation... but I hope it conveys what I am looking for

Comment: `memmove`, I believe.

Comment: You want shifting exactly 32 bits? Or you want ananswer for variable amounts of bits to shift?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, so you need to make up your mind.   Do you want to shift values in the array one element along, or do you want a shift of 32 bits?    An `int` is not necessarily 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the long way home...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array_size = 5;
    int array[] = {5, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int i;
    for (i = array_size - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        array[i+1] = array[i];

        if (i == 0)
            array[i] = 0; //whatever you want
    }

    // not necessary, just print the change
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
        printf("%d ", array[j]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @COLDSPEED suggested in the comments, `memmove` does very close to what you are expecting.

`void *memmove(void *str1, const void *str2, size_t n)`

**NOTE**: `n` is the total size in bytes to move. From moving `32` bits you might want to make space for 1 int I guess. (size of int is machine dependent). So, with `memmove` you can shift 1 byte. Not 1 bit.

And the main purpose of `memmove` is just to copy. Hence it should not be any better than straight forward copying. Both should take O(n) times.

Conventional method:

```
for (i = 5; i > 0; i--)
    arr[i] = arr[i-1];
arr[0] = 5;
```

Here is a sample code, using `memmove` doing the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    // Printing before state
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    // The shift operation
    memmove(arr+1, arr, 4*sizeof(int));

    // Inserting at the beginning
    arr[0] = 5;

   // Printing after state
   printf("After memmove:\n");
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf ("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 
After memmove:
5 1 2 3 4
```

Here is an article if you want to learn more about mmove: [memmove-in-c/c++](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memmove-in-cc/)